# How would I get a full range voltage reading from a pressure sensor?

Tags: sensor, arduino

I am making an application using the DIY Force Sensitive Resistor (FSR) taken from [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Force-Sensitive-Resistor-FSR/?ALLSTEPS). The resistance of this sensor typycally ranges from 20kOhm when at rest to 9kOhm when pressed.

How would I convert these resistance values to a signal where 0v corresponds to the rest condition and 5v corresponds to the "pressed" condition so that I can read it with an Arduino?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want a signal range from 0V to 5V. Don't we all :-)? Let's go for a different approach and see where that gets us.

Starting point: cheapest and most simple solution.

That would be a series resistor to create a voltage divider. That's the absolute minimum. I've noticed that people don't give that resistor much thought, the just pick a nice round value like 10k\$\Omega\$. But I found that there's an optimal value for this.

[image]

The curve shows the voltage difference between the minimum and maximum reading (9k\$\Omega\$ and 20k\$\Omega\$ resp.) as a function of the series resistor (in k\$\Omega\$). See, it indeed has a maximum. That's easy to find if you remember that

\$ \left(\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)' = \dfrac{f'(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x) \cdot g'(x)}{g^2(x)} \$

The difference \$V_{MAX}\$- \$V_{MIN}\$ has an extremum for

\$ \dfrac{d}{d R_X} \left(\dfrac{R_{MAX}}{R_{MAX} + R_X} - \dfrac{R_{MIN}}{R_{MIN} + R_X}\right) = 0  \$

Solving for \$R_X\$ gives

> \$ R_X = \sqrt{R_{MIN} \cdot R_{MAX}} \$

A beauty!

So in our case the series resistor will be 13.42k\$\Omega\$, you can check this on the graph. Placing the resistors between 0V and +5V this will give us an output range of [2V, 3V]. That's the maximum range you can get with 1 resistor(*).

Is it enough? The Arduino has a 10-bit ADC, so this range will give you a range of 200 discrete levels. That should give a sufficient accuracy for a DIY sensor. So no other components like opamps needed.

---

(*) The accepted answer gives a 1.9V range, but it has the **wrong equations**. It's impossible to get a higher range than 1V with 1 resistor and only a +5V supply.

Comment: +1. This should get more upvotes. Everybody needs a resistor divider for a variable resistor every now and then, and then why not use the optimum range instead of that silly 10k series resistor?

Answer (score 5):

You need a negative voltage to be able to make a resistor voltage divider going to 0V. I'll assume you have +5V and -5V available.
Place your variable resistor \$R_X\$ between +5V and GND. Now you need to find the value for a pull-down resistor between GND and -5V. Now that's easy; you want 0V out when the variable resistor is 20k\$\Omega\$, so the pull-down also has to be 20k\$\Omega\$ because the whole thing is symmetrical.
Next we have to find out what the output voltage of the divider will be when \$R_X\$ is 9k\$\Omega\$. We note that the current through \$R_X\$ is the same current as the current through the pull-down resistor, so

\$ \dfrac{5V - V_O}{9k\Omega} = \dfrac{V_O - (-5V)}{20k\Omega} \$

Working this out gives us \$ V_O = 1.9V \$.
Now all that remains to be done is scale the 0V..1.9V to 0V..5V. For this we use an **RRIO** (Rail-to-Rail I/O) opamp as a non-inverting amplifier

[image]

If you select \$R1 = 18k\Omega \$ and \$R2 = 47k\Omega\$ you'll get an output voltage range of 0V..5V for \$R_X\$ of 20k\$\Omega\$..9k\$\Omega\$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would be a voltage divider that gives you 5V at 9k and decreases as the resistance increases.  You can play with various resistor combinations in [this voltage divider calculator](http://www.raltron.com/cust/tools/voltage_divider.asp). It's going to be a linear progression, however.

Comment: You can't make a divider that gives you 5V if all you have is 5V.